# How do I view logistic regression coefficients from each bootstrapped iteration using R

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, bootstrap

I am relatively new to both `R` and bootstrapping.

My data set consists of a large number of variables, with the aim of generating a logistic regression model to predict a binary yes/no outcome.

As an example, I have created a 7-parameter model for which I am looking to bootstrap for a means of internal validation using the code below.

```
model = glm(outcome ~ parameter1 + parameter2 + etc..., 
            family = "binomial", 
            data = DATA)

logit.bootstrap = function(data, indices){
  d = data[indices, ] 
  fit = glm(formula(as.character(model$call)[2]), data = d, family = "binomial") 
  roc = pROC::roc(response = fit$y, 
                  predictor = fit$fitted.values)
  c = pROC::coords(roc,
                   x = "best", best.method = "youden", best.policy = "random",
                   ret = c("sensitivity", "specificity", "ppv", 
                           "npv"))

bootn = 10
set.seed(123)
logit.boot = boot(data = DATA, statistic = logit.bootstrap, R = bootn, 
                  sim = "ordinary", strata = DATA[,1])
```

Question:

I understand that for each bootstrapped iteration, the code will randomly sample individuals from my population and call the `glm` regression using the set parameters in the model. Each bootstrap iteration will deliver slightly different coefficients for each parameter based on the population sampled.

I would like to be able to view the coefficients generated for each bootstrapped iteration for each of the 7 chosen parameters to assess for stability. I essentially want to ensure the sign of each parameter does not change over the bootstrapping process. Obviously, I won't be checking all 1000, but is there a way to output this or at least 10-100 bootstrapped iterations?

Cheers

Comment: are you asking about checking the bootstrap estimates during the bootstrap itself, i.e. online, or after the bootstrap is done?

Comment: What does `logit.bootstrap` return? It doesn't seem like a correct `R` function.

Comment: @utobi I was hoping to check the bootstrap estimates of the coefficients after the bootstrap done. For example, if the coefficient estimate for parameter 1 is 1.34 in the stepwise regression, I would like to see what the values of this are in each bootstrapped iteration to see how much it varies when different populations are sampled. Essentially a way of checking the stability of the coefficients.

Comment: Ok. what about my second comment?

Comment: @utobi I think logit.bootstrap just contains the formula of the model and the code for ROC generation to be called for each bootstrap iteration. That said, this was a code given to me that I am still trying to fully understand.

Comment: the function misses a return and `}`.

Comment: check my answer below and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments above, your example is not replicable (e.g. you didn't provide the data and the statistic to be provided to boot is not correctly implemented), I'll show you a toy example using the `mtcars` dataset. If you are interested in checking the bootstrap estimates of the $\beta$'s, this example should be enough; e.g. the object `betahat.boot$t` below contains what you are looking for.

To run the bootstrap procedure in this example I find it easier to use the `car` package, which is just a wrapper around the `boot`

```
library(car)
m1 <- glm(am~wt + hp, data=mtcars)
  
betahat.boot <- Boot(m1, R=999) # same object as returned by a call to boot

# the object named t, contains the bootstrap estimates
head(betahat.boot$t)

# run a histogram of the bootstrap estimates for the intercept
hist(betahat.boot$t[,1])
```

[image]